# How to get rid of Unchecked call to 'compareTo(T)' warning?

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I have a generic class to represent an interval in a line of values.

```java
public class Interval<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    private boolean isStartInclusive;
    private T start;
    private T end;
    private boolean isEndInclusive;

    //constructors and getters and setters

}
```

I have a list of this interval of same type. And I am trying to sort them, based on their starting value.

So if the list was

```
{[1,2], [0,3], [-10,4]}
```

I am trying to get

```
{[-10,4], [0,3], [1,2]}
```

or

If the list was

```
{['e','v'], ['a','d'], ['c','f']}
```

I am trying to get

```
{['a','d'], ['c','f'], ['e','v']}
```

The code for sorting is below.

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<Interval<T>> sortIntervals(List<Interval<T>> intervals) {

    Interval[] intervalsArray = intervals.toArray(new Interval[0]);
    Arrays.sort(intervalsArray, (o1, o2) -> o1.getStart().compareTo(o2.getStart()));

    return Arrays.asList(intervalsArray);

}
```

But the line where `Arrays.sort` is called, there is a compiler warning: `Unchecked call to 'compareTo(T)' as a member of raw type 'java.lang.Comparable'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unchecked warning comes about because of your raw-typed array, `new Interval[0]`.

Note that you're not sorting `intervals`, you're sorting a copy of it, and then discarding the sorted copy.

Why bother going to an array?

```
intervals.sort(/* your comparator */);
```

Also, your comparator is unnecessarily complicated:

```
Comparator.comparing(Interval::getStart)
```

Comment: Thanks, understood that it is because of the array. I am aware of `Comparator.comparing()` method. Used lambda in question, because I thought it most people would know it. Now that I think of it, I do not even know why I went with an array.

Comment: Edited the question. I wasn't discarding it, I edited the code to be in one line in the question here, so it was an oversight there

Comment: Still, @AndyTurner's suggestion is spot on: just use the `.sort` method on your list. If you can't because you're on Java 7 or lower, use `Collections.sort` instead. Use it like this: `List<Interval<T>> copy = new ArrayList(intervals); copy.sort(Comparator.comparing(Interval::getStart)); return copy;`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire ofc you mean `new ArrayList<>(intervals)`, right? ;)